# 1305 - PROCEDURE db.delete_catelog_item does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I just created a procedure `(name : 'delete_catelog_item does')` in the database `(name : db)` and tried to run that procedure.Then i get an error like this `#1305 - PROCEDURE db.procedurename does not exist` .

My Query

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `delete_catelog_item`(IN itemtocatid INT(11),IN shopinid INT(11),OUT out_put BOOL)
BEGIN
     DECLARE cont INT(11);
     DECLARE itemid INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
     SELECT a.ItmId INTO itemid FROM mas_shop_item_to_category as a INNER JOIN mas_shop_item as b ON (a.ItmID=b.ItmID AND b.IsDelete!=1 AND b.ShopID IN (SELECT ShopID FROM mas_shop WHERE ShopID=shopinid OR ParentID=shopinid)) WHERE a.ItmToCatID=itemtocatid AND a.IsDelete!=1;
     IF itemid!=0 THEN
             UPDATE  mas_shop_item_to_category SET `IsDelete` = '1' WHERE ItmToCatID=itemtocatid;
             SELECT count(ItmToCatID) INTO cont  FROM mas_shop_item_to_category WHERE ItmId=itemid AND IsDelete!=1;
             IF cont=0 THEN
                UPDATE mas_shop_item SET `IsDelete` = '1' WHERE ItmID=itemid;
             END IF;
             SET out_put=TRUE;
     ELSE
             SET out_put=FALSE;
     END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;


Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
MySQL client version: 5.1.41
PHP extension: mysql
```

I can't figure out the actual reason, but when i check the procedure in my database it was there.
Please help to find the issue.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message you gave, it looks as though you've attempted to `CALL` your procedure by the name `procedurename`, whereas your `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement gave it the name `delete_catelog_item`.  You'll need to `CALL` it by the name with which it was defined!

Comment: 1305 - PROCEDURE db.delete_catelog_item does not exist, this is the actual error message which i get. I tried to call procedure using the same name which i created.

Comment: @LucilSandaruwan: Okay.  Perhaps you should edit your question to correct the message in there?  Is `db` the name of the database in which you created the procedure?

Comment: @LucilSandaruwan: But was the `delete_catelog_item` procedure created in that database?

Comment: Eggyal i could find the issue, thanx for your help

Answer (score 0):

I coul'd figure out the solution, The issue was on the db name. It was named with `"."` like `"first.second"` after i change that name the issue was not there. thanx for helping me.